# Loading large JS object working in NodeJS but not in NextJS

Tags: node.js, json, object, next.js

In one NodeJS app I have a function that simply imports a large (140MB+) object from a JavaScript file, as so:

```
import bigObject from '../../../seeds/bigObject.js';

export default async function importObject() {

  // Get structural files (deep copy otherwise data persists)
  let seed = bigObject;
  let object = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(seed));

   /* Process and modify object */

  return object
}
```

This function is called seamlessly all over the backend with the following statements, without any error:

> let object = await importObject()

However, in another app, from a NextJS backend, if I try to load this same object as such:

File 1:

```
import bigObject from "./bigObject"

export default async function importObject() {
    let seed = bigObject
    return seed
}
```

File 2 (in /api folder):

```
import importObject from '../../objects/importObject'

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const session = await getSession({ req });

    try {
        let object = await importObject()

        return res.status(200).json({ status: 'Successfully fetched object'})
    }
    catch{
        return res.status(401).json({ status: 'Error fetching object' })
    }
}
```

The app just crashes and I get the following error:

> <--- Last few GCs --->
>
> [6450:0x5363870]   754725 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 2044.8 (2068.3) ->
> 2044.6 (2066.3) MB, 423.1 / 0.0 ms  (+ 15.2 ms in 8 steps since start of marking, biggest step 14.8 ms, walltime since start of marking 440
> ms) (average mu = 0.231, current mu = 0.123) f[6450:0x5363870]
> 755180 ms: Mark-sweep 2045.8 (2066.3) -> 2045.5 (2070.3) MB, 452.5 /
> 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.130, current mu = 0.004) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
>
> <--- JS stacktrace --->
>
> FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap
> out of memory  1: 0xb09980 node::Abort() [node]  2: 0xa1c235
> node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]  3: 0xcf77be
> v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool)
> [node]  4: 0xcf7b37
> v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char
> const*, bool) [node]  5: 0xeaf3d5  [node]  6: 0xebf09d
> v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace,
> v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]  7:
> 0xec1d9e v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int,
> v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin,
> v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]  8: 0xe832da
> v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool,
> v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [node]
> 9: 0x11fc026 v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int,
> unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node] 10: 0x15f0a99  [node]
> Aborted (core dumped)

At first I thought I was possibly loading this file into the client side, but considering the file placement in the project structure that wouldn't make sense.

Also, the object inside the file is a massive json array like this:

```
let JSONObj = [
    {
        /*Data*/
    }
]
export default JSONObj
```